# How do you create a new collection in Solr

Tags: apache, collections, solr

I installed Apache Solr and followed the tutorial and successfully created a collection, indexed and searched data.
I wanted to move on to the next exercise so I deleted the collection in the UI.
I tried to create a new collection but I keep getting an error.
What do I need to do to create a new collection?
I am running an instance of Solr on 2 nodes.
Here is the command I executed:

```
bin/solr create -c films -s 2 -rf 2
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: Solr's startup log should show you the actual issue - Solr is failing to start properly for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the cluster on your local machine, try Solr Admin in a browser: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~collections. You can click the "Add Collection" button to create a new collection.